# Implementing background process in a dummy C++ shell

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been trying to mimic `&` in my dummy shell.
The foreground process works fine, but as soon as I include the `&` symbol, it doesn't behave as expected. The program shows unexpected behavior. It first executes the process (which should not be executed as a foreground process) and then it just freezes until I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Here is the snippet of my code.

```cpp
if(background)
{
    int bgpid;
    pid_t fork_return;
    fork_return = fork();
    if(fork_return == 0)
    {
        setpgid(0,0);
        if(execvp(path, args) == -1)
        {
            bgpid = getpid();
            cout<<"Error\n";
            return 1;
        }
        else if(fork_return != -1)
        {
            addToTable(bgpid);
            return 1;
        }
    }else{
        court<<"ERROR\n";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

[Output Image is also attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1CX6.jpg)

Comment: This needs a [mcve].  What's being shown is not sufficient.

Comment: @selbie What all things can I add to make it more clear?

Comment: A complete program of small enough size that only shows the problem at hand (not your complete homework assignment)  that we can paste into a text file, compile, run, and debug.

Comment: Your `else if(fork_return != -1)` is in the wrong place. It needs to be one level up.